# Restsharp - Exception due to XElement property

Tags: restsharp

I need to make a REST request and pass an object which has a property of XElement type.

The object:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public XElement PropertyXml {get;set;}
}
```

The code:

```
var testObj = new Test();
testObj.Property1 = "value";
testObj.PropertyXml = new XElement("test");
var level1 = new XElement("level1", "value111");
testObj.PropertyXml.Add(level1);

var client = new RestClient();

client.BaseUrl = new Uri(string.Format(_url));
var rRequest = new RestRequest(_address, Method.POST);
rRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
rRequest.AddBody(testObj);
var response = client.Execute(rRequest);
```

I get a 'System.StackOverflowException' at the line with AddBody call. 
PS I can pass a Test object using HttpClient (I use the PostAsJsonAsync method) instead of Restsharp.

Any ideas would be appreciated ..

Comment: Which version of restsharp are you using? If you use a version above 103 you need to set back the JSON seralizer to the JSON.net with `rRequest.JsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();` where the is comming from https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/86b31f9adf049d7fb821de8279154f41a17b36f7/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestSharp has no inherent knowledge of XElement, and `AddBody` will attempt to serialize it like it would any other POCO type - by traversing its properties. You can see this process getting stuck in an infinite cycle quite easily:

```
testObj.FirstNode.Parent.FirstNode.Parent....
```

Your best bet is to change the type of your `PropertyXml` property to a simple POCO type that the XML structure can easily map to. Something like:

```
public class PropertyStructure
{
    public string level1 {get;set;}
}

public class Test
{
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public PropertyStructure PropertyXml {get; set;}
}
```